# mysqli_stmt_fetch returns number

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

This is my first attempt at a prepared statement and instead of returning a single text element, I'm getting a number instead.  The number `1` to be specific.  Somebody said its got something to do with counting the records but I'm not sure how to turn it off.

```
function primary_include2($url_keyword)
  {
    $link = select_db();
    $query = "select file_path FROM primary_includes WHERE url_label=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $url_keyword);

    if ($result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)); 
      {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $file_path);
        $path = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        return $path;
        }
    mysqli_close($link);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
function primary_include2($url_keyword)
{
    $link = select_db();
    $query = "select file_path FROM primary_includes WHERE url_label=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $url_keyword);

    if ($result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)); 
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $file_path);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        return $file_path;
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

because mysqli_stmt_fetch returns true/false if a record was retrieved or not. The actual values are stored in variables indicated to mysqli_stmt_bind_result.